# Python get list of all user's in object that will not result in error

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am going try and explain this as simple as possible.

I have a google analytics object called `analytics` from a function called `initialise_analytics_reporting`.

Using this object I am getting data for a specific user using a function `get_UserActivity`:

```
def get_UserActivity:
    return analytics.userActivity().search(
                body={
                    "viewId": VIEW_ID,
                    "user": {
                        "type": "USER_ID",
                        "userId": user_id
                    },
                    "dateRange": {
                        "startDate": time,
                        "endDate": "yesterday"
                    },
                    "activityTypes": [
                        "PAGEVIEW", "EVENT"
                    ]
                }
            ).execute()
```

I am iterating through a list of `user_id`'s. If the `user_id` does have data, certain operations will be performed (which is working well). If the `user_id` does not have data, it still loads and results in an error (which is fine, but takes super long).

The problem I have is the loading bit for user's without data, it takes too much time while iterating through a very long list of user's to check.

Is there some way that I can determine before running `get_UserActivity` if the user has data or not? Or maybe even within `get_UserActivity`, as long as the entire loading process that results in error can be avoided.

(In other words, is there a way to get a list of all user's within the object that will have data and only iterate through them, instead of testing whether each user has data)

Comment: Whats taking a long time the call to google?

Comment: Yes, so I am trying to figure out how to bypass that if there is no data for the user.. for example, I have 1000 users and only 10 were active. Now a call to google needs to be made for each user.. instead of only calling those who were active

Comment: There is not other method you can use your stuck with the amount of time your call takes.

Comment: The problem you are having with the speed and no data for many users, I think, is related to google quotas on their api. Try time.sleep(1) between the calls, and see if that helps you. 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas